# How do I edit a unique column reference as foreign key in another table in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have one `master` table having column `keywords varchar(120)` as Unique and it is reference to another table `**cmp_keywords**` as a foreign key. Now how can I edit the column `keywords` value from `master` table and `cmp_keywords` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your foreign key with the option `ON UPDATE CASCADE`. Then just update the master table (correct term is parent table), then your child table will be updated automatically.

From the top of my head

```
ALTER TABLE cmp_keywords DROP FOREIGN KEY <foreign_key_name>, 
ADD FOREIGN KEY my_new_fk_name (cmp_keywords_column) ON UPDATE CASCADE REFERENCES master_table(keywords);
```

should do it. If not, figure out the correct syntax with this [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html).

Comment: You are right but small changes in your query syntax it will be                                                ALTER TABLE cmp_keywords DROP FOREIGN KEY <foreign_key_name>, 
ADD FOREIGN KEY my_new_fk_name (cmp_keywords_column) REFERENCES master_table(keywords) ON UPDATE CASCADE;